# Is the solution of $\;\int\frac1{\cos^2x(1-\tan x)^2}dx=\frac1{1-\tan x}+C\;$ or $\;\frac1{\tan x-1}+C\;$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

Here is my solution

$\begin{align}
&\int\frac1{\cos^2x(1-\tan x)^2}dx\\ 
&=\int\frac{\sec^2x}{(1-\tan x)^2}dx=\int\frac{du}{(1-u)^2}=\int\frac{dv}{(v)^2}\\
&=-\frac1{v}+C\\
&=-\frac1{1-u}+C\quad{(**)}\\
&=-\frac1{1-\tan x}+C\\
&=\frac1{\tan x-1}+C
\end{align}$

My textbook says the answer is  $\;\displaystyle\frac1{1-\tan x}+C\;.$

I get the fact that the negative sign can be omitted because of the arbitrary constant C, but how are these two answers the same? They're two different functions with different ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $1-u=v$ then $-du=dv$. You missed the minus sign.

Comment: oh that's funny. X D

Comment: You are funny too especially when you say the negative sign can be omitted because of the arbitrary constant $C$.

Comment: please excuse me I've just started integration